# PHP Download stops on 99% with download manager

Tags: php, content-length, http-content-range

I have a server with files, and people can download the files. I use this code to send the download:

```
<?php
function dl_file_resumable($file, $is_resume = true)
{
    //First, see if the file exists
    if (!is_file($file)) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid Request");
        die("<h3>File Not Found</h3>");
    }

    //Gather relevent info about file
    $size = filesize($file);
    $fileinfo = pathinfo($file);

    //workaround for IE filename bug with multiple periods / multiple dots in filename
    //that adds square brackets to filename - eg. setup.abc.exe becomes setup[1].abc.exe
    $filename = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE')) ?
                  preg_replace('/\./', '%2e', $fileinfo['basename'], substr_count($fileinfo['basename'], '.') - 1) :
                  $fileinfo['basename'];

    $file_extension = strtolower($fileinfo['extension']);

    //This will set the Content-Type to the appropriate setting for the file
    require 'mineTypes.php';

    // Check if the file extension is in $ctype_array & return the value. If not, send default.
    $ctype = array_key_exists($file_extension, $ctype_array) ? $ctype_array[$file_extension] : 'application/force-download';

    $is_resume = ($is_resume && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']));

    //check if http_range is sent by browser (or download manager)
    if($is_resume)
    {
        $arr = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
        if(isset($arr[1]))   
            list($size_unit, $range_orig) = $arr;
        else list($size_unit) = $arr;

        if ($size_unit == 'bytes')
        {
            //multiple ranges could be specified at the same time, but for simplicity only serve the first range
            //http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-http-range-retrieval-00.txt
            $arr3 = explode(',', $range_orig, 2);
            if(isset($arr3[1]))
                list($range, $extra_ranges) = $arr3;
            else
                list($range) = $arr3;
        }
        else
        {
            $range = '';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $range = '';
    }

    //figure out download piece from range (if set)
    $arr2 = explode('-', $range, 2);
    if(isset($arr2[1]))
        list($seek_start, $seek_end) = $arr2;
    else
        list($seek_start) = $arr2;

    //set start and end based on range (if set), else set defaults
    //also check for invalid ranges.
    $seek_end = (empty($seek_end)) ? ($size - 1) : min(abs(intval($seek_end)),($size - 1));
    $seek_start = (empty($seek_start) || $seek_end < abs(intval($seek_start))) ? 0 : max(abs(intval($seek_start)),0);

    //add headers if resumable
    if ($is_resume)
    {
        //Only send partial content header if downloading a piece of the file (IE workaround)
        if ($seek_start > 0 || $seek_end < ($size - 1))
        {
            header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
        }

        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
        header('Content-Range: bytes '.$seek_start.'-'.$seek_end.'/'.$size);
    }

    header('Content-Type: ' . $ctype);
    header('Content-Length: '.($seek_end - $seek_start + 1));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

    //reset time limit for big files
    set_time_limit(0);

    //open the file
    $fp = fopen($file, 'rb');

    //seek to start of missing part
    fseek($fp, $seek_start);

    //start buffered download
    $bytes = 0;
    while(!feof($fp))
    {
        print(fread($fp, 1024*8));
        flush();

        $bytes = $bytes + 1024 * 8;

        ob_flush();        
    }

    fclose($fp);
    exit;
}
```

When I download files through my browser everything is fine, but when I download it through download managers (like IDM) - the download stops on 99%.

What's wrong?

Comment: If it fails just on download managers, then it's a client-sided issue. Try with different download managers, it might just be an issue with the one you're using.

Comment: @DaveChen It happens also to others, not just for me

Comment: I think you'll need to do some debugging on this one. Try `wget` on the command line, you should be able to send range headers with a request. I expect all full chunks are working fine, but the last (incomplete) item is breaking in some way. See what is in the response headers for that part.

Comment: I see `Content-Length`. Make sure your calculation is right *and* you don't have transparent HTTP compression. (Try whether removing it fixes the issue.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `ob_flush` first and `flush` after.

`ob_flush` flushes output buffers you created with a function like `ob_start`

`flush` flushes buffered output of the PHP script itself to its caller.

Your last `ob_flush` puts more stuff in the PHP scripts buffer, but it doesn't get `flush`ed, because you `exit;`